# rowStyleClass function seems no to be called on datatable

Tags: primeng

I'm using angular 2.4.1 with primeng 1.1.4 but I tried with 1.1.3 and 2.0.1 with no luck.

I'd like to conditionaly change style of rows according to their content with `rowStyleClass` but it seems that the referenced function `customRowClass` is never called.

Here is the html code :

```
    <p-dataTable [value]="products" [rowStyleClass]="customRowClass">
      <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
```

and the summary of the component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  providers: [DataTableModule, SharedModule]
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  products: Product[] = [];

  constructor(
    private productsService: ProductsService
  ) { }

  public customRowClass(rowData, rowIndex): string {
    console.log('styling')
    return "text-gray"
  }

  …
}
```

There is no log inside the console, the row text and its html remains unchanged.

Any idea on what I did wrong ?